# Access Denied when saving a file, Windows 8 App

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-8, windows-8.1

i am using this code to add a node to an XmlDocument and then saving it to an existing file, however i keep getting this error message:

> Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

The code i am using is this:

```
            string xml = string.Empty;

        StorageFolder storageFldr = Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
        storageFldr = await storageFldr.GetFolderAsync("Scores");

        StorageFile sf = await storageFldr.GetFileAsync("Scores.xml");
        xml = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sf, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);

        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.LoadXml(xml);

        IXmlNode xNode = xDoc.CreateElement("score");
        xNode.InnerText = "Hello this is a test";

        xDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xNode);

        await xDoc.SaveToFileAsync(sf);
```

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: use Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder to store application data. follow this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700361.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem, but this worked for me:

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder sf = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("EMP", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists); 
StorageFile st = await sf.CreateFileAsync("Employee.xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists); 
await dom.SaveToFileAsync(st);
```

Comment: Thnx, i have discovered that the APP doesn't have access to the installation folder so we have to use the "%APPDIR%" equivalent for the Win8 Apps.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible without your application having elevated privileges (trusted application - with certificate or an OOB app).

You can set your app up as an out of browser application by following this guide.

[How to: Configure an Application for Out-of-Browser Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833073%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

However this maybe possible by using isolated storage to save - then modify the XML.

see this example [XML File with IsolatedStorage](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/aa741f4f-8b4b-4623-ba49-4d312f873d2c/xml-file-with-isolatedstorage?forum=silverlightnet)

Comment: Actually this is a Windows 8 APP, not a web browser silverlight app

Comment: Ah my bad! are you sure the InstalledLocation is not read-only? i remember reading something about that once..

Comment: I have found a solution, i have to use the ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder because that is the only place my app has full access to.